# Google Cloud bucket and all files disappeared. Says bucket exists when I try to recreate

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, bucket, stateless

Logged on to my Wordpress site to find all images and media missing.
I'm using WP-Stateless plugin. Tried to re-sync, but it relayed that all local and remote files are missing.Logged into Google Cloud and no bucket is listed for the project.Tried to recreate the bucket with the same name and it refuses saying the bucket already exists. This is a church website with hundreds of on audio files and graphics. What can be done to recover the previous bucket, and assure this doesnt happen again? I've had no issues with the setup for a couple of years. Hoping someone can help.

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to the Google Cloud Support team yet? If not, it might be a good idea to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to https://cloud.google.com/support-hub/ and open a ticket or post in the forums, which are monitored by Google. Google should be able to restore a backup of yoru bucket.

Comment: I guess because we are at a free level, we have no access to support of any kind. Do I need to sign up for some sort of premium service to get support? If so, it says I can't go back to a free option, but I don't see any sort of pricing. So not sure if we can even afford to do so. Any idea what I should do in our case?

Comment: Post in the community forums; they are monitored by Google support.